# Why is this question closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/42951/1027) asks if there's going to be a 7th *Star Wars* film.  The asker heard it was going to be made, and seems to be asking for confirmation.  The question received many downvotes, and was closed.

Why was it closed?

Comment: I wasn't one of the close-voters, but I *would* have marked it as a dupe of [Plans for more sequels to Star Wars?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/568/plans-for-more-sequels-to-star-wars)

Comment: Maybe because the OP didn't bother to try and Google the information?

Comment: @JackBNimble When we got rid of '[General Reference](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2400/1027)', 'you didn't google this' ceased to be a valid close reason.

Comment: The answer's in the question, that turns it into a statement.  The FAQ also says "Facts easily found on a reference site" are off-topic; that sounds like "you didn't Google this" to me.

Comment: @MatthewRead Looks like we need to update the FAQ there.  That's from when we had General Reference/Too Localized.

Comment: I wasn't sure what to do here when I saw it on hold, because it really is a dupe, as @phantom42 said. Surely I don't vote to reopen to then vote to close as a dupe? Even though the close reason isn't really right?

Comment: @TonyMeyer & phantom42 Can one of you post an answer that basically says 'this should be closed as a dupe'?  I can mark that as answer and take care of fixing the question's close reason myself.

Comment: IIRC, I VTCed, or considered to doso, as "Real life, not SciFi related" - mostly, because it seemed like a troll. But upon reading this Q, I think I was wrong to VTC for that. Good catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there is no longer a general reference/too localized close reason, the question is a dupe of [Plans for more sequels to Star Wars?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/568/plans-for-more-sequels-to-star-wars) .